Why Safari cannot connect to some websites with "No connection to internet" error although Firefox and Chrome can
I have a macbook air M1 with macOS 13.6.1 (not the latest I know).
For weeks now, Safari cannot connect to some websites (e.g. stackoverflow) with a "No connection to internet" error. Some other websites work properly. I don't have any problem with Firefox and Chrome.
I think this is tied to another problem : I am asked to reconnect to my iCloud session but there is an error : "A connection error to ID's Apple server happened" (in french "Une erreur de connexion au serveur de l'identifiant Apple s'est produite.")

I have verified the DNS (cloudflare's), rebooted in safe mode, tried with another user' session, cleared the caches… with no success.
The issue is when connected through iPhone shared connection. Everything is fine on my home's network.
Any idea would help.

I get that with dodgy sites usually via faceb**k. Closing that page and opening a new one for a different site works.

Could be an iCloud private relay or Safari firewall/security issue?

I forgot to say that the issue is only when connected through iPhone shared connection. Everything is fine on my home's network.
